# Why does SQL Server Profiler trace skip records?

Tags: sql-server-profiler

I have a SQL Server Profiler trace and it's working for all commands.

But the profiler skips one record like below:

[image: A pic from my trace]

Comment: typically it's memory related to the client when running real-time.  if you save to a file and enable checkbox `Server processes trace data`, it won't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insert a large amount of data, for example more than 1 MB, into SQL database in one single operation, the chance are that SQL Profiler is going to skip this operation, leave all fields blank, and mark as “Trace Skipped Records”. Don’t worry. The operation is still inserted into database, and only SQL Profiler skips the operation.

[Source of answer](https://ijianhuang.wordpress.com/2018/04/29/sql-profiler-trace-skipped-records/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20insert%20a%20large,Don%27t%20worry.)